# How to keep recvfrom listining in visual studio 6

Tags: c++, udp, multicast

I am working in Visual Studio 6.0  Visual Studio C++  Win XP
I have an application where a UDP broadcast sends out a message to which there should be a unique response.   On this UDP network there can be arp traffic etc.
I need the recvfrom call to listen in order to sort through unwanted messages.  I have found that poll() is not supported in Windows.
I have found that select() is not support in Windows XP.
Is there anything else that I can implement that will constantly listen and let other processes happen in the application.
Is pthread the only option???

Thanks

Comment: `select()' is part of Winsock 2, 1997. It has been supported since long before Windows XP.

Comment: In fact `select()` was part of Winsock 1 unless I am much mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the MSDN documentation and none of the socket APIs mention anything prior to Vista, however I'm guessing that's a matter of XP not being supported anymore.

I've been able to use `select` under Windows XP with no issue.  You may have issues with Visual Studio 6 however, at it was released 3 years before XP.  I would recommend upgrading to a newer version of Visual Studio, of which there are free variations.